# RTFPipe invalid html

Tags: c#, html, rtf

I have a requirement to convert RTF into HTML.
My issue is that the HTML needs to be strictly formatted with all matching tags, else I cannt feed it into an XmlDocument (part of the requirement).

I am using RTFPipe

```
var wWorkingText = RtfPipe.Rtf.ToHtml(strRTF);
```

The resulting html is technically pretty html, but I am missing closing tags and I am getting error stating

```
"End tag 'div' does not match the start tag 'p'"
```

this is caused by code like this

```
<div style="font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri;">
<p style="text-align:left;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;;font-size:9pt;margin:0;">
    <strong>2023/07/31, 12:08, HEADING</strong>
</p>
<p style="text-align:left;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;;font-size:9pt;margin:0;">
</div?
```

The unclosed "p" is obviously the kicker.
Is there a way to enforce STRICT converting to html from RTF?